# How do I find the joint CDF from this joint PDF?

Tags: probability

I have $f(x,y)=3x$ for $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$ and I want to find $F(x,y)$.

In lecture, our prof showed us how to do this the following way: [image]

I tried replicating this on my own, but used $\text{d}x\text{d}y$ integration for the area under $A$. i.e. I integrated $3x$ first over $x$ from $0$ to $y$, and then over $y$ from $0$ to $x$. However, I got a different answer. Same thing for the area under $B$.

Why does the order of integration seem to matter here? Do I have to change the bounds of the integral when I evaluate $\text{d}x\text{d}y$, as opposed to $\text{d}x\text{d}y$? If so, I can't really see how they would be different. For part $A$, $x$ is clearly running between $0$ and $y$ and $y$ is clearly running between $0$ and $x$.

Comment: Your way is in fact simpler, because for any $\tau_2$ between $0$ and $y$, $\tau_1$ will vary from $\tau_2$ to $x$:
$$F_{X, Y}(x, y) =
\int_0^y \int_{\tau_2}^x 3 \tau_1 d \tau_1 d \tau_2 =
\frac {y (y^2 - 3 x^2)} 2, \\
0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1.$$

Comment: Whoa, you're right! How could you break it up into the two parts like he did it though (to get the same answer)?

Comment: I got the sign wrong, of course:
$$\int_0^y \int_{\tau_2}^x 3 \tau_1 d \tau_1 d \tau_2 = \frac {y (3 x^2 - y^2)} 2.$$
You can write it as
$$\int_0^y \left( \int_{\tau_2}^y + \int_y^x \right) 3 \tau_1 d \tau_1 d \tau_2.$$
The first double integral is over a triangle, the second is over a rectangle.

Comment: Ok I see this! I tried this same thing but leaving t1 and t2 as x and y, which made the triangle area = 0. So I guess you have to change those variables. Is that to distinguish between the condition variables and the actual variables in the function?

Comment: Correct, you should distinguish between free variables and bound variables. You can already see this problem in your screenshot, you have to keep track of different meanings of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The order matters because it cancels out the variables. Our joint pdf is given by

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{align}\begin{cases} 3x &  0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1\\ \\ 0  &  \textrm{ for  everywhere else } \end{cases} \end{align}$$

now the CDF is defined as

$$ F(x,y) = P(X \leq x ,Y \leq y) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy $$

then we have

$$ \int_{x=0}^{y} \int_{y=0}^{x} 3x dy dx  \tag{1} $$ 
$$ 3\int_{x=0}^{y}xy\Big|_{0}^{x} dx \tag{2} $$
$$ 3 \int_{x=0}^{y} x^{2}dx = 3\frac{x^{3}}{3}\Big|_{0}^{y}\tag{3} $$ 
$$ 3\frac{y^{3}}{3} = y^{3}   \tag{4} $$

for the second part

$$ 3\int_{x=y}^{x}\int_{y=0}^{y} x dy dx  \tag{1}$$
$$ 3\int_{x=y}^{x} xy \Big|_{0}^{y} dx   \tag{2}$$
$$ 3\int_{x=y}^{x} xy dx   \tag{3}$$
$$ 3\frac{x^{2}y}{2} \Big|_{x=y}^{x}   \tag{4}$$
$$ \frac{3}{2}(x^{2}y - y^{3})   \tag{5}$$
$$ \frac{3y}{2}(x^{2} - y^{2})   \tag{5}$$

now we have

$$ F_{X,Y}(x,y) = A+B = y^{3} + \frac{3y}{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})$$

Do you have to change the bounds? If you simply switch $dx $ and $dy$ but not the bounds what do we get for instance on the first one

$$ \int_{x=0}^{y} \int_{y=0}^{x} 3x dx dy  \tag{1} $$ 
$$ \int_{x=0}^{y}  \frac{3x^{2}}{2}\Big|_{0}^{x} dy  \tag{2} $$ 
$$ \frac{3}{2}\int_{x=0}^{y}  x^{2} dy  \tag{3} $$ 
$$ \frac{3}{2}  x^{2}y\Big|_{0}^{y}  \tag{4} $$ 
$$ \frac{3}{2}  x^{2}y  \tag{5} $$

which is different from $y^{3} $

Comment: But what if I wanted to write the integrals with dxdy? Is it possible to change the bounds of integration to be able to do this here and get the same answer?

Comment: There something called Fubinis theorem. you can simply switch the order you integrate however the bounds are important. I need some coffee but I can work that out... you should note that there is a negative sign in yours but he simply switched the order of $(x^{2}-y^{2}) $

Comment: I edited it with an example changing the order $ \int_{x=0}^{y} \int_{y=0}^{x} 3x dx dy $

Comment: I get that you can't just leave the bounds the same. But why can't you re-order the same bounds? For example, for part A, why can't you equivalently write 3xdxdy with x going from 0 to y and y going from 0 to x? How would you change the bounds to get the same area for that part, but using dxdy integration?

Comment: I attempted to reorder the bounds and get it but it wasn't really possible.